# Apple mail matching signatures with account aliases possible?

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I use a gmail account with apple mail. It's very annoying that I have to pick a matching signature everytime I decided to change the from email alias.

Is there anything I can do that will allow me to match up a signature with each alias email address?

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of professionnal use of E-mail, I abandonned `Gmail` and `Mail` many years ago.

I use `Thunderbird` ( [Thunderbird home page](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) ) which is much more secure, lets you configure it exactly the way you are looking for through the concept of "identities". You can define many "identities" per account, each one being defined by:

- a name
- a "From:" field
- a "Reply-To:" field
- an "Organization:" field
- a signature (in HTML or text)

I use this E-mail client as a much faster interface to `Gmail` letting me answer with the identity required and permitting my correspondant to answer me with my appropriate reply address.
[image]

As a collateral advantage, you will most probably discover many other advanced function to use in `Thunderbird`.

Comment: Out of interest, how is it more secure?

Comment: I wanted something that was completely integrated with the OS. Kinda sucks that you can get something so basic accomplished.

Comment: Mr Smith doesn’t use more than one E-mail and one signature, when they should (buy a pizza versus candidate for a job). Sorry about this but your need is rather a professionnal one, as seen from the sausage vending machine !

Comment: @unknowndomain: because of the number of functions in the `Preferences > Security` and `Preferences > Privacy` settings. These are functions that are usable by beginners and advanced users. To give you 2 (from my point of vue) winning settings :[return] `Privacy > ☐ Allow remote content in messages`, [return]` `Security > Junk > √ Enable adaptive junk filter logging`.